# Android Build.SERIAL - is it hex?

Tags: android

Android offers the hardware serial number as an option for identifying the device (guaranteed if there is no TelephonyManager DeviceID). The documentation says:

```
public static final String SERIAL

Added in API level 9
A hardware serial number, if available. Alphanumeric only, case-insensitive.
```

All the ones I've seen are hex, as in no alphabetic chars above 'F'. Is this guaranteed?

Comment: as per the doc, apparently not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not.  The documentation doesn't say that it is, and it seems that [HTC has Zs in their serial numbers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=472891).

> The new format will read similar to HT[year][month][day]. I presume
>   that they wish to be this precise for warranty purposes.
>
> The month format shall be between 1 - 12, but the day format will take
>   a slightly different shape.
>
> Days will go from 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H,
>   J, K, L, M, N, P, R, S, T, V, W, X, Y, Z. Day Z represents day 31.